# How to use a function across multiple js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am pretty new to javascript, but I am trying the best I can and I could not find the answer or something that helped me.

I am trying to put spaces between thousands, but in different JS files. So I would like to define that function in an other file, so I can reuse it. This works:

```
var parts = item['effect-value'].toString().split(".");
parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
parts.join(".");
```

What I have tried is the following:

Global file:

```
   function addSeparator(){
       parts.toString().split(".");
       parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
       parts.join(".");
   }
```

or something like this…

```
$.fn.addSeparator = function(options) {
    var $this = this;

    var parts = options.replace;

    $this.html({
        parts.toString().split(".");
        parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
        parts.join(".");
    })

    return $this;
};
```

The other files:

```
var parts = item['effect-value'];
addSeparator(parts);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: What's the question then?

Comment: As long as the function is in the global scope (i.e. you include the file with the `.js` function in it on the pages that call it) you can simply make a call to the function like so `var parts = addSeparator(item['effect-value']);`

Comment: Hello Brad and gdoron, it does not work and I can't tell why… It's a little bit struggling for me still.

War10ck thank you, I will try to figure that out!

Comment: War10ck thank you, I did not understand at first but now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just running the function, not aplying to the var.

Try using like this:

```
     function addSeparator(input){
           var parts = input.toString().split(".");
           parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
           return parts.join(".");
       }
     var parts = addSeparator(item['effect-value']);
```

Comment: That does not seem to work. The console says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined", but thank you for your reply!

Comment: what's the value of item["effect-value"]?

Comment: It's json data (pure numbers)? Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the functions are in the global scope *and are already loaded*, they should work.

What's the order of your JavaScript file calls in your HTML? Files with dependency on other files should come after the ones on which they depend.

IE - Global, Separator, JS that uses Separator

Comment: Thank you for your comment Shauna. It seems that I forgot to save the function into a variable.